# Bulk replace or remove a character in file names

Tags: c#, comments, file-handling

I have a little utility I'm writing that will let the user replace 1 character for another in a filename from a specific directory the user chooses.
The idea is to let the user replace an "_" or any other character they want with any other character they want or just remove it altogether.

EDIT: After taking the information I learned from your responses and a little Google searching to understand how those commands worked, I came up with this code.  Any feedback would be nice.

```
    private static void myremovechar()
    {
        //subprocedure to modify file names by removing or replacing characters   NO SUB DIRECTORIES

        //Ask user where the files are located and store value in string mybadfilesource
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Where are your files located");
        Console.WriteLine(@"Example: D:\folder\subfolder\");
        string mybadfilesource = Console.ReadLine();

        //Ask user what character to remove and store value in string mychartodelete
        Console.WriteLine("What character do you want to remove");
        Console.WriteLine("Only 1 Character allowed");
        string mychartodelete = Console.ReadLine();

        //Ask user what character to replace mychartodelete with and store value in string mychartoreplace
        //if user just hits enter, mychartodelete will just be deleted
        Console.WriteLine("What character do you want to replace it with");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to just delete previously selected Character");
        Console.WriteLine("Only 1 Character allowed");
        string mychartoreplace = Console.ReadLine();


        try
        {
            //store list of files from mybadfilesource in var filelist
            var filelist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(mybadfilesource);
            foreach (string file in filelist)
                {
                    //renames the files by Replacing mychartodelete with mychartoreplace
                    var newfile = string.Format("{0}{1}",Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Replace(mychartodelete, mychartoreplace),Path.GetExtension(file));
                    File.Move(file, Path.Combine(mybadfilesource, newfile));
                }
        }
        //Error Checking Process - Prints error message
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        //tell user the process is done and return to Main Menu
        Console.WriteLine("Finished - Press Enter to Return to Main Menu");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear(); 
        Main();
    }
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: You can't modify the list in a foreach loop.

Comment: `"Visual Studio 2013 is telling me the replace method wont work here."`  is it throwing a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Comment: you're calling replace on your `IEnumerable myfilenames`, which doesn't exist.  That's your first problem.

Comment: And, `Replace` is a method on `string` objects, not `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` objects. And the `select` is not doing what you think it does (it's not doing anything at all here).

Comment: Visual Studio is Saying 'Error 1 `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Replace' and no extension method 'Replace' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` So where should I start at fixing this?  I thought `select` was helping me to only select the file name not the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of wrong here:

> 1. You're calling Replace on the wrong variable
> 2. If you use the right variable, you'll still get an error for modifying a variable in a foreach loop
> 3. You're not *really* renaming anything, you're not applying anything back to the actual file.

try this:

```
 foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mybadfilesource))
 {
     var newfile = string.Format("{0}{1}",
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Replace(mychartodelete, mychartoreplace),
            Path.GetExtension(file));
     File.Move(file, Path.Combine(mybadfilesource, newfile));
 }
```

Be sure to just get the filename without the path or extension, or else you'd be changing those too

Comment: It does exactly what I needed. It also doesn't work on the Parent Dir or Sub Dir and files.  Which is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks